# What does MonkeyTalkAPI.js file do?

Tags: testing, scripting, monkeytalk, monkey-testing

In each monkeytalk project, there exists a MonkeyTalkAPI.js file in the "lib" folder. It is same for all the projects. WHat does this file actually do?

To run a javascript file, we need a browser. SO how does this file get executed?

Answer (score 1):

It declares common objects (Device, Application, Script etc.) that are used by your xxxMTTest.js